# check if TcpLayer or udpLayer is not null

Tags: c#, tcp, pcap.net

i am using pcap.net to read packets from a pcap file and save them to new pcap file after anonymization(change some fields). i have a problem. some pcap files have incorrect or incomplete packets e.g they have not tcp layer or payload.
i want to know how check if tcplayer exist?

it is part of my code:

```
**TcpLayer tcpLayer = (TcpLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.ExtractLayer();                                 
UdpLayer udpLayer = (UdpLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Udp.ExtractLayer();**
```

the pcap files that have no tcp or udp layer hava error in these lines.
how can i check if tcpLayer  is not null before this line?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some validation code:

```
if (packet == null)
  return;

if (packet.Ethernet == null)
  return;

if (packet.Ethernet.EtherType != EthernetType.IpV4)
  return;

if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4 == null)
  return;

if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol != IpV4Protocol.Tcp &&
    packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol != IpV4Protocol.Udp)
  return; 

if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Transport == null)
  return;
```